# Openshift CORS ERROR 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors, openshift

There are duplicate questions related to CORS. But none of the solutions worked for me.I am running my application on Openshift Cloud.I have installed [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package as middleware. This is the error.

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://evil.com/, *', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   'http://my-app-name.rhcloud.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**Server Side Code**

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

//rest of the code

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address);
```

**Client Side Code**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my-app-name.rhcloud.com:8000/',{
    'forceNew':true
});
```

I am using **angularjs** and **express** framework.

Comment: hit the same issue: openshift-sub-domain.rhcloud.com can not access example.com during wordpress redirects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin on OpenShift using Node.js, express, and socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889940/access-control-allow-origin-on-openshift-using-node-js-express-and-socket-io)

Answer (score 25):

Have you installed a plugin to enable/disable cors on your browser? I did it and it was the origin of my problem. I uninstalled it and the 'http://evil.com' origin header was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to turn off your browser extension for CORS.

Comment: Uh... but then the browser blocks it as a CORS prohibitedcross-origin request.  Isn't the extension supposed to be what gets around that?

Answer (score 1):

I spent about 50 hours with this stupid issue with evil.com and finally I've got a solution. Author of CORS chrome extension did it on purpouse to get our attencion on dangers with cors. Just uninstall this garbage, and everything will work fine. Damn!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is normally caused by the CORS plugin in chrome. Disabling the plugin should fix the issue for you.